# Retrieve Custom Attributes for Standard View

Tags: android, view, custom-attributes

I've defined a custom Attribut testAttribute for EditText and applied it in the Layout.
This compiles as expected, so i think it's available.

```
<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
cst:testAttribute="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

Know, i need to read the testAttribute programatically in my Action, which i don't know how to do it.
I know how to do it in a custom view, but i need it in the standard view.

Anyone ideas on that?

Answer (score -1):

on your custom View you do the following:

```
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle); 

            final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,  R.styleable.MyCustomView, defStyle, 0);
            // the default value is true
            // get the custom value progammatically
            testAttribute = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyCustomView_testAttribute, true);

           // make sure to recycle
           a.recycle();
    }
```

Hope it helped

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all